# Connection between contra-/covariant vectors in SR and complex numbers?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

If we take a spacetime with one spatial dimension, we can write a vector as $A^\mu=(t, x)$. This is a **contravariant** vector, and we can calculate the **covariant** vector by multiplying it with the Minkowski metric:
$$
A_\mu=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    1& 0\\0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
A^\mu
=\begin{bmatrix} 
    t\\-x
\end{bmatrix}
$$

(I'm not sure if this is notationally valid, since I might be mixing up tensor notation and matrix notation, but you get the idea. )

We can then calculate the **proper distance** using the einstein summation convention: $A^\mu A_\mu$.

---

We can see that coindidentally, the conjugate of a complex number transforms in the same way. If we have a complex number written as a $2\times 1$ matrix $\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 
    a\\bi
\end{bmatrix}$

Then the complex conjugate of $\alpha$ is found by

$$
\alpha^*=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    1& 0\\0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\alpha
$$

---

So we see that the **relation between contravariant and covariant vectors** in spacetime is **similar to** the **relation between complex conjugates**.

**Is there a deeper connection between the two, or is this just a mathematical coincidence with no significance?**

Comment: The essence of Minkowski metric is the invariance of the speed of light. How to connect this to the conjugate of a complex number it is arduous.

Comment: I think they're formally identical. Both $A^\mu$ and $\alpha*$ can be thought of as covectors, i.e., as linear operators that act on a vector and give a real result. Isn't this equivalent to the old-fashioned custom of writing four-vectors as $(ict,x,y,z)$? BTW, you also get some expressions when you deal with quaternions that look a lot like the metric and inner products in 3+1 dimensions.

Comment: I think you have some typos in your post.  You seem to have rediscovered the old fashioned way of describing the "proper distance" without using a metric (or with 4-dim Euclidean inner product).  Not sure if there is a "deeper meaning" to this.  We abandoned that method 100 years ago or so.